# Терминал мака вместо кириллицы отображает '?'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, macos, utf-8

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n;
    string str;
    cout << "Введите строку: " << endl;
    cin >> str;
    int l = str.size();
    cout << l << " " << str << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
        cout << str[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Данный код считывает слово и выводит каждый его символ через пробел, но при вводе кириллицы выдается следующий результат:

```
Введите строку: 
цуйафы
12 цуйафы
? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
Process exited with status 0
```

Проблемы начинаются при выводе размера слова, число не является правильным.

Comment: Размер русских букв в utf-8 2 байта. Если хотите выводить по символу, то нужно копиравать эти 2 байта в строку типа `char *` Как отличить однобайтный utf-8 символ от многобайтного (и узнать его длину (м.б. до 4-х байт)) см. в [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: есть ссылка на источник, в котором написано как это сделать?

Comment: Добро пожаловать в XXI век. Символы кодируются в Unicode. Используйте wstring со товарищи.

Comment: @alexey.qqq  По ссылке **utf-8**  щелкали?

Comment: @user_587, для реального программирования у ввода wstring есть одна пренеприятная особенность, поток ввода необратимо портиться, если на вход подать недопустимый (не представимый в utf) символ. Так что, лучше оставайтесь в старом добром XX веке и обрабатывайте сами. Впрочем, это не мешает читать байтовый поток и переводить его в unicode (w_char) самому (ну, и самому же отвечать за все ошибки)

Comment: @user_587, std::wstring не является кроссплатформенным решением - `wchar_t` имеет размер, зависящий от ОС и компилятора (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).